# How should I declare a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet so I can close it in C#?

Tags: c#, office-interop, com-interop, excel-interop

I am having a hard time making sure my COM objects are closing so I am not leaving an EXCEL.EXE process running in the background.  I have learned that the double dot and chaining of declarations is bad as this could leave COM objects hanging around.

Does anyone know how to fix this line of code so I can properly close and release the worksheet COM object?

```
worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[strName];
```

EDIT:  I have tried using app.Quit() when I am done executing this line to close the open Excel object, however this does not work.  app.Quit() works if I call it before this line however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in order to let the EXCEL.EXE process quit you do not have to explicitly release all COM objects you used. The Runtime Callable Wrappers (RCW) which are implicitly created for you by the .NET runtime when you obtain another reference to a COM object are collected by GC and this releases underlying COM objects.

All you have to do is to call the Quit method, release RCWs references and let GC collect them.

```
//This runs the EXCEL.EXE process.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
//This locks the excel file either for reading or writing 
//depending on parameters.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(...);

...

//Explicitly closing the book is a good thing. EXCEL.EXE is alive 
//but the excel file gets released.
book.Close();

//This lets the EXCEL.EXE quit after you release all your references to RCWs
//and let GC collect them and thus release the underlying COM objects. 
//EXCEL.EXE does not close immediately after this though.
app.Quit();
app = null;
```

Second, if you leave so-called double-dot code lines be, you do not create any memory leakage. Garbage collector will collect the RCWs and will release the COM objects sometime i.e. when it finds it right.

And finally if you wish to release the RCWs and corresponding COM objects explicitly to minimize the memory pressure at all costs, you could explicitly call the GC to collect the RCWs after you release your references to them or even explicitly release the underlying COM objects BEFORE the GC collects the RCWs. Be careful though. This last way leaves you in responsibility for the fact that the remaining RCWs are never used after that or you are going to have an exception.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Application app = new Application();
Workbooks books = clsExcelApplication.Workbooks;
Workbook book = books.Open("...");
Sheets sheets = book.Sheets;
Worksheet sheet = sheets["..."];

...

//Trying to be as explicit as we can.
book.Сlose();

//Revese order. Using FinalReleaseComObject is even more dangerous. 
//You might release an object used inside excel
//code which might lead to some dreadful internal exceptions.
int remainingRefCount;
remainingRefCount = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
remainingRefCount = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
remainingRefCount = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book);
remainingRefCount = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(books);
app.Quit();
remainingRefCount = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

Keep in mind. If you manually release COM references than EXCEL.EXE lifetime does not depend on the RCWs and you can nullify them when you like...

```
sheet = null;
sheets = null;
book = null;
books = null;
app = null;
```

In the most explicit case, do not forget to check the return from the Marshal.ReleaseComObject. If it is not zero, somebody else is holding a COM reference to your underlying COM object besides the RCW you just released.

Comment: I found as long as you make sure you closed everything you handled and issue excelapp.Quit it does go - I did find some issues in some premade exporttoexcel code I found, but on also setting excelapp=null at the end, this made sure that nothing was hanging on to anything

Comment: The GC does not release the COM components. You have to explicitly do it.

Comment: @Enigmativity GC does not release pure COM objects obtained via some API but it does release COM objects obtained via Runtime Callable Wrappers. In the case with excel it does release them all right.

Comment: @BugFinder Setting excelapp to null does not change much. This just releases your reference to the RCW corresponding to the excel app COM object. It does not affect the end of the EXCEL.EXE process and it does not ensure that you do not hold some other reference to some other RCW (COM object) like a a workbook or a worksheet.

Comment: No but I did find it made a practical difference in the long run, I never investigated why but if I comment that line out, excel.exe's stay open. with the null, they all go. reliably and on time.

Comment: @Zverev Eugene I have tried using the app.Quit() however the process is still left active.  Is this because I am declaring my application as a ApplicationClass instead?

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

Comment: @BugFinder You are right that the app.Quit does not close the EXCEL.EXE immediately, I did not notice that before, +1.
It looks like you have to release your references to all the RCWs and let the GC collect them. I edit the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @Crobota Thanks to BugFinder I updated the answer. Looks like you have to release all your references to the RCWs you obtained and let GC collect them in order to ensure EXCEL.EXE to close.

As for the ApplicationClass, that depends on what it really is. If it is a mere COM import declaration which bypasses the RCW then yes, you might have to explicitly release it with System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);

I will check that later.

Comment: @ZverevEugene Explicitly releasing it with the GC ends the process on my development machine, however it does not when running from my server.  (Might have been good to say this is a web app...oops).  I am currently running app.Close(); GC.Collect(); System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app); with no success at ending the process on the server.

Comment: @Crobota On server you might see what you see because the GC works differently and it does not collect all the RCWs when you wish it to. For server GC the RCWs might be very small objects that might be out of priority for collection.

Try releasing all the RCWs explicitly i.e:

Workbooks books = app.Workbooks;

Workbook  workbook = books.Open(...);

Sheets sheets = workbook.Sheets;

Worksheet sheet = sheets[...];

And COM-release all of those explicitly.

Comment: @Crobota. Server-side automation of Office applications is explicitly *not* supported, just so you know: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

Comment: @Crobota In a simple IIS-based case I would try using a signle excel Application instance shared between the requests. This can leave you with a single long-running EXCEL.EXE which serves all you Workbook instances in parallel. Very scary. Very wrong. Might work.

Comment: @Crobota Try to explicitly close the Workbook as well. workbook.Close();

Comment: @ZverevEugene I have had limited success with your suggestions because of the amount of code that is using it, but it appears to be working!  I just need to track down everywhere the COM objects are being used.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Crobota In such a case I create a wrapper around the 'dangerous' API which is excel in your case. Just make sure no code besides the wrapper has a reference (using) of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. That's a very linear refactoring. It may sound tough but I do not know another way to ensure everything is released in time. The same happens with any unmanaged resources like files, sockets, graphics, manual threads and so on.